# What Clause would most optimally create this query?

Tags: sql

So I don't have much experience with SQL, and am trying to learn. An interview question I came across had this question. I'm trying to learn more SQL but maybe I'm missing a piece of info to solve this? Or maybe I'm approaching the problem wrong.

This is the question:

We have following two tables , below is their info:

- POLICY (id as int, policy_content as varchar2)
- POLICY_VOTES (vote as boolean, policy_id as int)

Write a single query that returns the policy_id, number of yes(true) votes and number of no(false) votes with a row for each policy up for a vote stored

My first thought when approaching this was to use a WITH clause to get the policy_ids and use an inner join to get the votes for yes and no but I can't find a way to make it work, which is what leads me to believe that there's another clause in SQL I'm not aware of or couldn't find that would make it easier. Either that or I'm thinking of the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Show us the code you wrote.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I beg to differ. I think he needs PIVOT to transpose the Yes and No votes count.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have the code in front of me, so I couldn't post it. I suppose I could have thrown something together. Also there is no specific database so there is no way to specify. If you read the question, that's the only context I was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

I cannot answer *too* specifically, since you did not specify a DBMS, but what you will want to do is count or situationally sum based on criteria. When you use an aggregate function like that, you also need `GROUP BY`.

Here are two example tables I made with test data:

**policy**

```
| id | policy_content |
|----|----------------|
| 1  | foo            |
| 2  | foo            |
| 3  | foo            |
| 4  | foo            |
| 5  | foo            |
```

**policy votes**

```
| vote | policy_id |
|------|-----------|
| yes  | 1         |
| no   | 1         |
| yes  | 2         |
| yes  | 2         |
| no   | 3         |
| no   | 3         |
| no   | 4         |
| yes  | 4         |
| yes  | 5         |
| yes  | 5         |
```

Using the below query:

```
SELECT
  policy_votes.policy_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes_votes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_votes

FROM
  policy_votes

GROUP BY
  policy_votes.policy_id
```

You get:

```
| POLICY_ID | YES_VOTES | NO_VOTES |
|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 1         | 1         | 1        |
| 2         | 2         | 0        |
| 4         | 1         | 1        |
| 5         | 2         | 0        |
| 3         | 0         | 2        |
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07ce32/2) for you to try it out.

Comment: So from the looks of this I was on the right track, I don't have the code I was working on, I was doing this in SQL Fiddle for a while, but I guess this is more of an understanding on how the commands work with the information. I didn't understand how to differentiate the votes by policy_id, but I'm guessing that's handled by GROUP BY.

Comment: Exactly correct. The `SUM(CASE WHEN...` basically says ***if vote is yes, add a 1 to my total, if its a no, add 0 to my total*** etc. 

`My total` is then defined in the GROUP BY, where we `GROUP` those counts for each individual `policy_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p.id, p.content, 
Count(case when pv.vote='true' then 1 end) as number_of_yes,
Count(case when pv.vote='false' then 1 end) as number_of_no
From policy p join policy_votes pv
On(p.id = pv.policy_id)
Group by p.id, p.content
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Since the content is not required you might as well exclude the policy table from the query, using only the policy_votes

Comment: I thought policy id alone will not be sufficient. Content will make it more human readable.